# JS Client Side Controller on Apex

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

How can i access every element value of my **data.getReturnValue()** because my **c.getName** is expectedly return a list of values.

```
({

myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var getAllRelatedContact = component.get("c.getName");
    getAllRelatedContact.setParams({
        "textsearch" : component.find("textsearch").get("v.value")
    });
    getAllRelatedContact.setCallback(this, function(data){
        var vals = data.getReturnValue();
        for(integer i=0;i<vals.length;i++){
            alert(vals[i]);
        }
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(getAllRelatedContact);  
}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Danryl,

If you want to access any value in the client side controller, then you can give like,

```
for(i=0;i<vals.length;i++)
{

  alert(vals[i].Name);//by accessing field name like in list.


  }
```

Else, If you want to just display accordingly, You can use in `<aura:iteration>` as Ashwani told.

```
<aura:iteration var="opp" *items="{!v.nameXYZ}"*>
        <p><b>  {!opp.Name} -- {!opp.Status}</b></p>
    </aura:iteration>
```

In controller,

```
component.set("v.nameXYZ", data.getReturnValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write:

```
component.set("v.nameXYZ", data.getReturnValue());
```

Would be like:

```
({

myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var getAllRelatedContact = component.get("c.getName");
    getAllRelatedContact.setParams({
        "textsearch" : component.find("textsearch").get("v.value")
    });
    getAllRelatedContact.setCallback(this, function(data){
        var vals = data.getReturnValue();
        for(integer i=0;i<vals.length;i++){
            alert(vals[i]);
        }
        component.set("v.nameXYZ", data.getReturnValue());
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(getAllRelatedContact);  
}
})
```

`v.nameXYZ` is the attribute which expect list type value.

And if you want to show all items on page you can use `<aura:iteration>` tag